# CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT error for clEnqueueReadBuffer

Tags: opencl

I am trying to create a simple vecAdd function in OpenCL for the very first time and I am having problems with clEnqueueReadBuffer which gives out CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT which is actually an error of clSetKernelArg. I have done some hunting and found out that this is caused due to premature memory freeing. I am guessing that I am not doing that but the problem still persists.

Comment: Can you show the relevant host code (everything from buffer creation through to the `clEnqueueReadBuffer` call)?

Comment: I solved the issue. It was a problem of accessing a variable before declaring them.

Comment: @ShakHub I'm getting the same error, but I'm not sure whether your problem might be the same problem I have. Do you have more details on how you fixed it?

Comment: @bcdan Its been a long time since I worked on it. I will post my github link that I just create. Maybe you can take look there and see if you can solve your issue. Please let me know if you cannot understand the code.                                                                      https://github.com/shakhub/OpenCL